# Every element of a probability space contained in at least k of a family of n sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega, \beta, \mathbf{P})$ a probability space, and $B_1, ..., B_n$ are measurable sets ($B_i \in \beta$) such that every $\omega \in \Omega$ belongs to at least $k$ of the $B_i$'s. Then at least one $B_i$ has $\mathbf{P}(B_i) \geq \frac{k}{n}$.

My Ideas so Far: (1) For $k=1$ the statement is obvious because if we supposed by way of contradiction that $\mathbf{P}(B_i) <  \frac{1}{n}$ for all $i =1, ..., n$, then we would see that $\mathbf{P}(\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i) < \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{P}(B_i) < n \cdot \frac{1}{n} =1$ which contradicts the fact that every element belongs to at least one of them so the measure of the union should be $1$.

(2) The fact that every $\omega$ belongs to at least $k$ of the $B_i$'s tells me that the union of sets of the form $B_{i_1}\cap ...\cap B_{i_k}$ with $1 \leq i_1 < ... < i_k \leq n$ is equal to $\Omega$.

(3) Geometrically the result makes sense to me as taking a simple example like $\Omega = [0, 1]$ and three intervals such that their measures are all less than $\frac{2}{3}$ (here $k=2, n=3$) one can see that there will be some subset of the interval which is not the intersection of two sets.

So far I have tried induction on $k$ and using the inclusion-exclusion formula but to no avail, and I have been messing around with set theoretic identities but gotten nowhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis can be written
$$\forall \omega \in \Omega, \quad \sum_{i=1}^n {\bf 1}_{B_i}(\omega) \ge k \,.$$
Taking expectation of both sides,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i ) \ge k \,.$$
This implies that at least one of the summands on the left hand side must satisfy $P(B_i) \ge k/n$.